# What is this variation of MVC in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mvc, mvvm, mvp

I am working on sorting out my **Javascript** code. Currently I have views implemented without any Model or collection. Now I working on separating Model from View. So for this transformation, I am planning as follows:

```
         View --->  X  <--- | ---> Server
          <  Client side  >
```

Assumptions:

1. View will not have any data that is to be loaded form server.
2. X will talk to server and get the required data. Then X will fire event.
3. View will listen to events and update themselves accordingly.
4. X is not an exact replica of some entity on server. X will just take those entities/ data from server and then View can request this data from X.
5. There will be exactly one X for each View.

Now question is -- What is X called?
Options -- Model, Controller, ViewModel, Presenter, or anything else.
Or Is this very crude thing which can not have terminology?

Comment: So X and View will be client-side based?

Comment: @Daniel - Yes, both are on client side. Basically javascript. So X is a guy sitting on client side and talking to server for data.

Answer (score 1):

X is most commonly called a ViewModel. Controllerless [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) is what your implementation most closely resembles.

If your view is handling the events from X, it's similar to Model-View-Binder, kind of like [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), maybe without the declarative style.

I wouldn't worry so much about what it's called.  Worry about  **how/if it works**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you're not following any of the MV* patterns (yet).

In (very) loose terms:

- A View is strictly for presenting information and receiving input from the user.
- A Controller, Presenter, or ViewModel may have business logic as well as being the go-between for the Model and the View.
- A Model is a representation of the system's data.  It might be a direct access to the data store, or it might go through a data access layer instead.

"Model" is the closest layer that `X` seems to be approaching.  The Model layer does not need to be a direct representation of the information in the data store.  It just needs to present the data in alignment with the application / business domain.

You may find Martin Fowler's article on [GUI Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) worth reading.  Please note that he has updated the MVP pattern and moved it into two patterns, but you'll run across that while reading through his site.